# UnicodeEncodeError in Beautiful soup (python 2.7.1)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, sgml, sgmlreader

I am using Beautiful Soup 3.2 on python 2.7.1 here.

I have recently been trying to get something simple to work, but it
seems rather tricky:

I do the following:

```
temp=BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(urlList[1], None,15))
```

However, I get the error:

```
File "/home/foo/k/kat/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1519, in __init__
BeautifulStoneSoup.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/foo/k/kat/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1144, in __init__
self._feed(isHTML=isHTML)
File "/home/foo/k/kat/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1186, in _feed
SGMLParser.feed(self, markup)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 104, in feed
self.goahead(0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 143, in goahead
k = self.parse_endtag(i)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 320, in parse_endtag
self.finish_endtag(tag)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 358, in finish_endtag
method = getattr(self, 'end_' + tag)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfa' in
position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I run the same loop another time, sometimes, I also get:

```
File "/home/foo/k/kat/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1519, in __init__
BeautifulStoneSoup.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/foo/k/kat/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1144, in
__init__
self._feed(isHTML=isHTML)
File "/home/foo/k/kat/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1186, in _feed
SGMLParser.feed(self, markup)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 104, in feed
self.goahead(0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 143, in goahead
k = self.parse_endtag(i)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 320, in parse_endtag
self.finish_endtag(tag)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 358, in finish_endtag
method = getattr(self, 'end_' + tag)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
4-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How do I avoid this errors? Obviously something is wrong with the sgmllib.py.

I tried some solutions from SOF:

*] Tried `soup = BeautifulSoup(page, fromEncoding=<encoding of the page>)`
Result: Dosent work, same errors.

*] Tried upgrading my sgmllib.py from a 2.7.2 version onto my 2.7.1 verision 
Result: Dosent work, same errors.

*] Tried `html = BeautifulSoup(page.encode('utf-8'))`
Result: Dosent work, same errors.

I would appreciate any suggestions as to how to solve this encode error.

Comment: Seems like the page you are trying to parse has a difffernt encoding than utf-8. What did you try soup = BeautifulSoup(page, fromEncoding=) with?

Comment: Hi Bogdan, I tried soup = BeautifulSoup(page, fromEncoding="utf-8") However, I get the same errors.

Comment: And are you sure the encoding of the page you are trying to parse is "utf-8"?

Comment: @Bogdan, Yes, when I look (at the failed page) in firefox, Views-->Encoding, I see UTF-8.

Comment: Can you add the url you're trying to parse ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code in your module

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but "inside of your if name == "main":" - is this a piece of code to be inserted too? if yes, where should i include this code? sys.setdefaultencoding does not work. sys.getdefaultencoding returns ascii.

Comment: Updated code to show the right syntax as it was obfuscated by formatting.

Comment: That is absolute genius. The above code elimates the UnicodeEncodeError. What I seem to fail to understand is how the above code works. what does "if __name__ == "__main__":" do? Can you please explain?

Comment: @user7699 Recently i stumbled upon the same problem, so i decided to post this simple trick. :) Defaultsetting needs to be set if you work with Unicode and version of your Python interpreter<Python3 (like Python 2.7.1).                                                                                As for "if name == "main":  - it just checks if you execute current module directly without importing it-like-python mymodule.py (in commandline shell) If that check is true-it executes those 2 lines.See Mr Fooz'complete answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your explanation. That has solved the problem I had been struggling with for about 2 days now!